# How do I set the body for each step of wizard in `timeu-wizard` component?

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm new to **polymer** and I'm finding it difficult to set the Step Body.
i.e.
I have 4 steps :

- Get Personal Info (Fname,Lname,Gender,Age,etc)
- Get Credit Card info
- User Account Preferences
- Welcome On-board Message

Now each step have its own Page/Body/Div. How do i set that? So when i click next, the next Step body is displayed.

Comment: Have a look at the [polymer-cli](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli) which includes a starter kit that includes routing.

Comment: can you please add relevant code

Comment: This is the code i'm using
`<timeu-wizard id="default" steps='[{"Step1","Step2","Step3","Step4","Step5"}]' step="{{defaultWizardStep}}">`

Comment: and this is the repository
`https://github.com/timeu/timeu-wizard`

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct syntax. I'll write it here so if anyone new to Polymer (like me) needs it :

```
<timeu-wizard id="default" steps='["Step1","Step2","Step3","Step4","Step5"]' step="{{model.WizardStep$}}">
</timeu-wizard>
<iron-pages selected="{{model.WizardStep$}}">
    <div>Step 0 page (The wizard is not started yet)</div>
    <div>Step 1 page</div>
    <div>Step 2 page</div>
    <div>Step 3 page</div>
    <div>Step 4 page</div>
    <div>Step 5 page</div>
    <paper-button raised id="next">Next</paper-button>
</iron-pages>
```